# Incorrect date value while creating Date field in InnoDB table MySQL database

Tags: mysql, innodb

I need to create a date field in InnoDB table but I get this error

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_name`  ADD `bdate` DATE NOT NULL  AFTER `another_field`;
MySQL said: Documentation
#1292 - Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'bdate' at row 1
```

Comment: Not sure about this one, but looks like your table already have data and adding a new column with `NOT NULL` isnt possible. Maybe forget the `NOT NULL` first then add some values and then add the `NOT NULL` or try include a `DEFAULT`

Comment: That worked thank you. You can add it as an answer. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Strict mode affects whether the server permits '0000-00-00' as a valid date: If strict mode is not enabled, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce no warning. If strict mode is enabled, '0000-00-00' is not permitted and inserts produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as well. For INSERT IGNORE and UPDATE IGNORE, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce a warning.**

You need to disable date strict mode or need to remove `not null` from `bdate` column.

Why it's happening?

You'r saying bdate is not null, it means all old records will have default date populated, since in your case `strict date mode` is enabled, it means your bdate values which default to `0000-00-00` will become invalid and server will throw the error, which you are seeing.

Though fixing database side may not be good Idea, its always better to do in `App layer` if possible.

Comment: No. Better fix the data or your application. You never know when such modes might get deprecated

Comment: @NicoHaase I do agree with you, and I have never intended to suggest, you fix your database, I was just pointing the problem and error, I hope you have read my updated response completely.

Answer (score 0):

You cant add a new Column with `NOT NULL` if your table already have rows.

Either create the column without the `NOT NULL` restriction then fill the column with data and then add the `NOT NULL` restriction.

Or add column with a `DEFAULT` value.